# 减/減 (Reduce/Subtract/Decrease/Diminish): What's it got to do with water?

Tags: meaning, characters, etymology, glyph-origin

So here we have 冫+咸 (or 氵+咸) = 减(減).

减(減) means something along the lines of reduce/subtract/decrease/diminish or what have you.

What has water got to do with this though?

Logically one would imagine 冫 (water) + 咸 (salty) = a reducing of *flavor*, thus giving reduce/subtract/etc.

**ShuoWen: (說文解字):**

> 損也從水咸聲

**Chinese Etymology**

> Phonetic Signific, of water 氵水 - can pour out of - decrease

So what's the deal?

What's going on here?

Comment: My mnemonic is "Ice is *decreased* by salt". Can't say anything about the etymology though.

Comment: The origin of the word is the name of a river. Quote from 山海经: 減水出焉北流注于海其中多鱤魚. The meaning of 'reduction' is somehow derived from that but I have no idea why... It may be related to some natural attribute of the river.

Comment: 咸 is phonetic in both 減 and 鹹 ‘salty’ (where 鹵 is semantic). It's not _water + salt_, but _water + [phonetic component]_. Think of water running through sand or your hands, or from a basin with a hole in it, gradually diminishing and disappearing. Makes good enough sense to me, at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think both "減" and "咸" exists in the ancient times, but for certain reasons scholars like to use "咸" in place of "減".

損也,從水,咸聲 == It has the same meaning as '損', water as glyph component, and the same pronunciation as '咸'.

In 管子·宙合, which was written before the early Han Dynasty, it says "左操五音，右執五味，懷繩與准鉤，多備規軸，**減** 溜大成，是唯時德之節。 .... **減**，盡也。溜，發也。 ...."

Comment: Good, but what you talk about is in the ancient Chinese in BC, and the examples are almost unable to be understood by persons whose mothertongue is not Chinese.

Answer (score -2):

咸 doesn’t mean salty here.

The word “salty” in traditional Chinese is 鹹. The left component 鹵(lǔ) is pictographic for the halides (actually the halides carried by a pouch). And the right component 咸(xián) is phonetic in this case. So 鹹 pronounced xián.

From traditional to simplified, 鹹 omitted the left component to 咸 retaining the pronunciation. But this character means “all” originally.

减 is irrelevant with any flavor. It is “water” + “all”.

So, you can think about that the water flux takes off a part of all, such as a tiny piece of a big rock in the river. This is reduce/substrate/decrease/diminish.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72107/discussion-on-answer-by-hao-fu---reduce-subtract-decrease-diminish-whats-i).