# How does 添's 2021 meanings appertain to its semantic component 水?

Tags: etymology

This feels like the opposite of [减/減 (Reduce/Subtract/Decrease/Diminish): What's it got to do with water?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/8688). I read [演 ＝ 氵+ 寅 but what's it got to do with water!? How did it get its modern meanings?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/9176). [I screenshot Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?searchChinese=1&zi=%E6%B7%BB#).

[image]

Please explain definitions 4-5 from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%B7%BB#Chinese), as they differ from the standard definitions 1-3.

> 4. (Cantonese) Modal particle expressing emphasis.
> 5. (Taishanese) need to (do something); have to

Answer (score 1):

添 is related to water because 添 is mostly referred to adding/refilling of liquid' e.g. 添酒，添水，添油 (add wine, add water, add oil)

酒 and 油 are not 水 but all characters related to liquid use 氵 as its radical, and 添 is too -- The most common and easy thing to add is liquid

添 = add --> also -->futhermore

Cantonese uses 添 as a modal particle expressing emphasis, which implies  'just remember/  be reminded'

Example:

唔記得買米 = forgot to buy rice

唔記得買米(添) = (oh/ouch/ *just remember*) forgot to buy rice

冇米點煮飯？ = how can dinner be cooked with no rice

冇米(添)！點煮飯？ = (oh/ouch/ *just remember*) there is no rice, how can dinner be cooked?

仲唔記得買米 = still/ also forgot to buy rice

仲唔記得買米(添)/ 仲(添)唔記得買米 = (furthermore), also forgot to buy rice

> (Taishanese) need to (do something); have to

Taishanese user please answer this part

Comment: Did you discuss 水 in your answer?

Comment: @hims I thought water is related to add is obvious, e.g. 添酒，添水，添油 (add wine, add water, add oil) The most common and easy thing to add is liquid. 酒 and 油 are not 水 but all characters related to liquid use 氵 as its radical, and 添 is too

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, it's not obvious how 'water' is related to 'add'. "The most common and easy thing to add is liquid." Perhaps, but I don't know chemistry and I'm not sure. I'll believe you though.